# Iterating through an array and returning first 10 results

Tags: php, json, for-loop, curl, foreach

So I am trying to iterate through what appears to be json feed, I am using the following code to get all the array results, however, how do I return specific items, lets say the first 6 or 10 ?

```
<?php 

$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
$url = 'https://weedmaps.com/api/web/v1/listings/green-valley-medicinal/menu?show_unpublished=false&type=dispensary';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
$menu_data = json_decode($result, true);
            foreach($menu_data['categories'] as $menu_item){
            foreach ($menu_item['items'] as $item) {
      echo '<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
      echo isset($item['image_url']) ? '<img class="media-object menu-item-photo" height="120" width="120" src="'.$item['image_url'].'">' : '<img class="media-object menu-item-photo" height="120" src="images/mmjicon.png">';
      echo '<h2>'.$item['name'].'</h2>';
      echo '<p>'.$item['body'].'</p>';
      echo '</article>';
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways you could do this.

Keeping your foreach loop, add a count, increment it, and break the loop  once it reaches 10.

```
$count = 0;
foreach(...) {
    ...
    if (++$count >= 10) break;
}
```

Comment: @AymenYaseen glad I could help.  Please mark the correct answer to show this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have control over the number of data is being retrieved, you can use a $counter to your foreach.

```
$your_limit = 6;
$counter = 0;
foreach($menu_data['categories'] as $menu_item){
    if ( ++$counter > $your_limit ){
        break;
    }        
    foreach ($menu_item['items'] as $item) {
      echo '<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
      echo isset($item['image_url']) ? '<img class="media-object menu-item-photo" height="120" width="120" src="'.$item['image_url'].'">' : '<img class="media-object menu-item-photo" height="120" src="images/mmjicon.png">';
      echo '<h2>'.$item['name'].'</h2>';
      echo '<p>'.$item['body'].'</p>';
      echo '</article>';
      }
    }
```